# Radio Service Software Motorola Syntor x9000

Tags: software, radio-programming, motorola

My name is Roger, I live in Sweden, have bought some old motorola synths x9000 transceivers that I need to reprogram, but have great difficulty finding the Rvn 4007E software as it should be.

Have tried Motorola direct but they do not have it left, they say, it seems to be very difficult to find it, I wonder if anyone here has it or knows where I can find it?

Comment: Try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=motorola+syntor+x9000+programming+software+download). I didn't follow any of the links, but some appeared to have software.

Comment: Note that even if you obtain the software you will need the right hardware to run it. This will include an old, slow computer (486 or older) running DOS, a RIB (Radio Interface Box) and a programming cable.